# Nginx reverse proxy goes to one server and not multiple

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse

I have two websites, ineedbabypics.com and ineedtoclose.com

I have updated both domain names A record to point to my public IP address.
The problem is I followed various online settings for proxy and can't get the simple redirect to work. When I type in both domain names in my browser, it both goes to ineedbabypics.com.

I want ineedbabypics.com to go to 192.168.1.96 and ineedtoclose.com to go to 192.168.1.83. Here are my server block settings:

```
#nginx.conf
    server {
            listen       80;
            listen       [::]:80;
            server_name  _;
            root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

            # Load configuration files for the default server block.
            include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

            location / {
            }

#ineedbabypics.conf
server {
    server_name http://ineedbabypics.com www.ineedbabypics.com;
    set $upstream 192.168.1.96;

    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://$upstream;
    }
}


#ineedtoclose.conf
server {
    server_name http://ineedtoclose.com www.ineedtoclose.com;
    set $upstream 192.168.1.83;

    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://$upstream;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this your full config? Because I don't think `proxy_redirect` does what you think it does

Comment: I updated it to the way it was before. That configuration did not work either.